# prometheus metric count based on value

Tags: spring, monitoring, prometheus, grafana

I am totally new to prometheus and any monitoring tool.
Basically I want to emit metric and draw histogram in prometheus based on value in request header.
For example: my REST API request header have a field 'id'

```
Header {id: "someid"}
body {some request body}
```

Now i want to draw a histogram/bar graph in prometheus/grafana  where x-axis is distinct 'id' field values and y axis should be count of the number of request that specific 'id' value as header.

How can we do that?

Comment: This is a question that would require a massive answer if you want all the details. But the gist of it is: Instrument your application -> Expose metrics -> Configure Prometheus to scrape it -> Connect Grafana to Prometheus

Comment: @trallnag can you please provide any link which can help.

Comment: Here is the client library for Java <https://github.com/prometheus/client_java>. In the most basic setup you want a counter (if you are only interested in number of requests) or histogram (if request duration is of importance to you) that you update every time you handle a request. Notice that you should not use Prometheus for data with very high cardinality (millions of different ids), at least it is not recommended.

Comment: Most likely there are already libraries out there that instrument a REST API for you. But I don't know if they support labeling with data from request